# Local install of GNU MP, how to access it from ld?

Tags: bash, compilation, g++, ld

I have a compiled local install of GMP:

```
/path/to/gmp
    .../lib/gmp.h
    .../include/[gmp_binaries.etc]
```

Now, I export the path, just to test the install; I'll add symlinks in some central location once I get it working:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/gmp:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

g++ -lgmp

// error: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgmp

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/gmp/include:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/gmp/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

g++ -lgmp

// error: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgmp
```

Basically, my question is: how do I connect my local libraries to `ld`?

(And the point is installing content without sudo, so I can't "just ____," for the most part)

Comment: `-l` requires a `-L` location to search in `g++`. What are you trying to do? Are you trying to make gmp? There should be a makefile in that path; you should be able to just call `make`.

Comment: @jeremysprofile I am trying to install a library which depends on gmp.  This library's configuration script is having problems discovering my local install.  I am attempting to figure out why it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-l` requires a `-L` location to search in `g++`. Make does not follow your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Make needs a specific location to search for specific libraries not included in `/usr/lib`

> `#  define library paths in addition to /usr/lib`
>   `#   if I wanted to include libraries not in /usr/lib I'd specify`
>   `#   their path using -Lpath, something like:`
>   `LFLAGS = -L/home/newhall/lib  -L../lib`

[From this site](https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/howto_makefiles.html)

Find your libgmp file, and link as follows:

```
g++ -L/path/to/libgmp/ -lgmp
```